# Adonis js how to mutate value when saving on model

Tags: typescript, adonis.js

Using Adonis js

When saving , im trying to mutate a ISO string to Datetime (reverse of serailizing DateTime fields to ISO string). Cant find a way to do this in model, like i would as a mutator in laravel. When I attempt to use beforeSave() hook to achieve this I get a type error because model is expecting DateTime not string type. Any ideas?

**Controller**

```
public async update({ request, params, response }) {
    let data = request.all()

    //Hopefully move this logic to model for date fields
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        if (['recievedAt', 'dueAt'].includes(key) && typeof value == 'string') {
            data[key] = DateTime.fromISO(value)
        }
    }

    const task = await Task.findOrFail(params.id)
    task.merge(data)
    await task.save()

    return response.status(200).send({ request, params: params.id, data })
}
```

**Model**

```
@column.dateTime({
    serialize: (value: DateTime | null) => {
        return value ? value.setZone('utc').toISODate() : value
    },
})
public recievedAt: DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to anything if you use [column.date or column.datetime](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/orm/decorators#columndate--columndatetime).

> The decorator self defines the **prepare**, **consume** and the **serialize** methods to ensure
>
> - You are constantly working with an instance of luxon.DateTime in your codebase.
> - The date is serialized as an ISO date.
> - The date is formatted correctly as per the underlying database driver.